# React Native: How to align inline text?

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I want to do this, where both of the texts are on 1 horizontal line and one of them is in the center and the other is on the right:

[image]

This is what I have, ignore the colors (it doesn't work at all):

styles:

```
  rowLabelText: {
    color: "#0B1219",
    fontFamily: Fonts.Knockout31JuniorMiddleWeight,
    fontSize: 16.0,
  },
```

Markup:

```
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', height: 30, flexWrap: 'wrap', backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red', justifyContent: 'center', alignSelf: 'center'}}>
        <Text style={styles.rowLabelText}>
          adjkfdasjkfaskj
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue', justifyContent: 'center', alignSelf: 'flex-end' }}>
        <Text style={styles.rowLabelText}>
          adjkfdasjkfaskj
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
```

[image]

I am having trouble. Could someone assist me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34753717/3597276

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your problem is with with `alignSelf` you want to use `alignItems`.

This is how your code will look like.

Your View:

```
<View style={styles.textContainer}>

     <View style={styles.leftContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.rowLabelText}>
          adjkfdasjkfaskj
        </Text>
     </View>

     <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.rowLabelText}>
          adjkfdasjkfaskj
        </Text>
     </View>

</View>
```

Your styles:

```
  textContainer:{
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 30,
    backgroundColor: 'green'
  },
  leftContainer:{
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  rightContainer:{
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
  rowLabelText: {
    color: "#0B1219",
    fontSize: 16.0,
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to center text with respect to the entire width of the screen while also having some text to the right side of the centered text is to use absolute positioning on the right text.

By using absolute positioning on the right text, it will not affect the position of the centered text.

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <View style={{flex:1, alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
        <Text>50%</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{position:'absolute', right: 20, backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
        <Text>+$0.80</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```